# Microsoft.XMLDOM object required

Tags: xml, windows, vbscript

I create a web page in Classic ASP. This page collect XML from request string using `Microsoft.XMLDOM` object.

```vb
Set XMLDocumentVar = Server.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
XMLDocumentVar.ASync = False
XMLDocumentVar.Load Request

Set NodeListVar = XMLDocumentVar.documentElement.childNodes

For Each NodeVar In NodeListVar
    Response.write NodeVar.nodeName
Next
```

This code was working before window updating. After getting yesterday update, this code does not work.

The "object required" error is raised when `.documentElement.childNodes` is used.

I know it is so strange. But there is no other problem before Windows updating.

How should I do?

P.S. My operation system is windows 7.

Comment: `Microsoft.XMLDOM` has been deprecated for years. Try `Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0`.

Comment: Its depend on what is comming inside `Request`. can you provide sample data ?